# Javascript Date Object Off by One Month

Tags: javascript, getdate

I understand that javascript counts the months starting from 0. However, I don't know how to account for this when getting a date in the future.

For example, when attempting to get the date for tomorrow, the following code returns everything correct except for the month (prints as next month):

```js
const weekday = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
const month =  ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];

var today = new Date();
today.setUTCDate(today.getUTCDate()+1);

let newDate = weekday[today.getDay()] +' '+today.getDate()+' '+month[today.getDay()]+', '+ today.getFullYear();

console.log(newDate)
```

Comment: `month[today.getDay()]` should be `month[today.getMonth()]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `today.getDay()` to `today.getMonth()`

```js
const weekday = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
const month =  ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];

var today = new Date();
today.setUTCDate(today.getUTCDate()+1);

let newDate = weekday[today.getDay()] +' '+today.getDate()+' '+month[today.getMonth()]+', '+ today.getFullYear();

console.log(newDate)
```